# Double list comphrension in ordinary speech

Tags: python, pandas, nested, list-comprehension, python-itertools

I've implemented the following list comprehension in my code, and it works:

```
[string for row in series for string in row]
```

Background: I had a pandas series of lists of strings. So each row of the series had a list, and each list had several strings. So I wanted to use a list comprehension to pull out all the strings from each list in the series and compile them into one big list.

The question: Just reading the syntax, I'm having trouble understanding inuitatively what's going on in the comphrension. Can anyone spell it out in plain english? For example, for a standard list comphrension ([x for x in z]), I might describe that as "a list with a x for every x in z."

I don't know if this is really a doable question, but I thought it was worth asking! Thanks.

Comment: “To understand it, just write it out as a nested for loop” - that’s what you should do. And consider writing it as a nested for loop. The difficulty of understanding “comprehension”s often makes them somewhat incomprehensible. Just use for loops - much quicker to write, much easier to debug, much easier to change - and use the time and energy saved to do something fun, or creative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All it does is flatten a list of lists so for example

```py
nested_list = [[1, 2, 3],
               [4],
               [5, 6]]
flat_list = [item for inner_list in nested_list for item in inner_list]

# flat_list will be [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

To understand it, just write it out as a nested for loop:

```
result = []
for row in series:
    for string in row:
        result.append(string)
```

basically it reads left to right as a nested loop, but the inner code comes at the start.

You can kind of see this by messing up the spacing in your original code:

```py
result = [
    string 
    for row in series # : <- pretend colons
        for string in row # : 
            # result.append(string) <- this bit just goes to the start in list comprehension land
]
```

By the way, you can apparently do faster using `itertools.chain` (but I'm not sure if that still applies on a `pd.Series`):

```
import itertools
result  = list(itertools.chain(*series.tolist()))
```

Comment: I doubt `itertools.chain(*nested)` would be faster, that requires a pass over the entire iterable to unpack it. Instead, use `itertools.chain.from_iterable(nested)`

Comment: This is a really helpful answer! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`numpy` is your friend. Use it and skip the for-loop

```
# sample series
s = pd.Series([list('abcd'),
               list('efgh'),
               list('ijkl')])
# concat your series
l = np.concatenate(s)


array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l'],
      dtype='<U1')
```

Comment: This might be a noob thing but for some reason I prefer to not use libraries when it's possible to do it in vanilla Python, but maybe using numPy here is just better form / better performing?

Comment: `numpy` will be significantly faster than using a for-loop with list comprehension or, in this case, using two for-loops

Comment: @KristianCanler pandas is already based on numpy so you might as well use it

Comment: I'm with @KristianCanler on this;   for string processing, numpy isnt necessarily faster than list comprehensions. Infact, I dare to say, it is slower, in a lot of cases. Of course, you have to run tests to affirm that. Besides, you can run lists comprehensions within Pandas. For numeric manipulations, yes numpy rules.